# Matrix factorization approximate products to solve math solution

Tags: mathematics, matrix-factorisation

**Problem**
Matrix factorization for approximating products how do we solve such that Z approximates products N, M. How to define the math formula for solve for Z approximtaes the products of N,M?

**Scenario**
Given matrix that has product N, product M.

**Proposal to problem**
Need a math solution to define the a problem which can be to make a prediction on product N, or M to determine if there are features that are latent.

**Constraints**
NMF exhibits constraints which: W≥0 and H≥0
products can be defined by a k-dimensional vector R with lower dimension that the original R with n*m dimensions. Hence, R with n*M = (W with n*r) (H with r*m)

**Author Level**
This math is for a entry level understanding on how to use matrix factorization for products N, M, to factor Z into approximations on the product N, M.

**Proposed code solution 1**
Computes an approximation of the user-item matrix Z as the product of matrices N and M

```
def matrix_approximation(N, M):
    Z = np.dot(N, M)
    return Z
```

**Proposed code solution 2**
to treat N to factor M product

````
def matrix_factorization(Z, k, steps=50, alpha=0.0002, beta=0.02): 
    m, n = Z.shape
    N = np.random.rand(m, k)
    M = np.random.rand(k, n)
    
    for step in range(steps):
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(n):
                if Z[i, j] > 0:
                    eij = Z[i, j] - np.dot(N[i,:], M[:,j])
                    for r in range(k):
                        N[i, r] = N[i, r] + alpha * (2 * eij * M[r, j] - beta * N[i, r])
                        M[r, j] = M[r, j] + alpha * (2 * eij * N[i, r] - beta * M[r, j])
        e = 0
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(n):
                if Z[i, j] > 0:
                    e = e + pow(Z[i, j] - np.dot(N[i,:], M[:,j]), 2)
                    for r in range(k):
                        e = e + (beta/2) * (pow(N[i,r],2) + pow(M[r,j],2))
        if e < 0.001:
            break
    
    return N, M
```
````

Comment: Dear @user1857373, welcome to the site. It is not clear at all what your question is. It seems that you would like to know more about matrix factorization. A google search would give you plenty of information about it. If you have specific questions about that, please specify them clearly.

Comment: Thanks Noe, I'm new to the data science stack. For the question, "how to write the math algorithm for NMF to work on solving a matrix factorization for products to be approximated on these products", Or in Python, how to define a matrix factorization for products N, M, to factor Z into approximations on the product N, M"

Comment: A simple google search gives many relevant results, both regarding [more theoretical information](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=neural+matrix+factorization) or more related to [implementations](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=neural+matrix+factorization+github). Please, check those. If you have specific questions about that, please feel free to ask here. Otherwise, your question is a bit too open. You can check the [help center](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to improve a question.